# CS50 - Why is return value 1 + collatz() and not just collatz()?

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int collatz(int n);
int main(void)
{
   int n = get_int("Enter your number: \n");
   printf("It took %i steps for %i to reach 1.\n", collatz(n), n);
}

int collatz(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
       return 1 + collatz(n / 2);
    }
    else if (n % 2 != 0)
    {
       return 1 + collatz(3 * n + 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why the 1 in `return 1 + collatz()` acts as a counter.

Basically this program prints out the numbers of steps that it takes for a number to reach 1 by dividing if it's even or 3n + 1 if it's odd. This is from cs50 recursion video. I don't understand why 1 in returns can act as counter, isn't it gonna add to the `collatz` function?

Comment: Think about it ... When you call `collatz` _and_ it's making a _recursive_ call to itself, the 1 represents the "parent" step [where the called function is the "child"]. (i.e.) you are adding 1 for the current call "depth"

Comment: Note that `collatz` [for a given recursion level] only returns 1 or 0 [e.g. start from the deepest level and work upwards]. Each level adds 1 to the count of the lower level.

Comment: because `collatz` have recursive call.

Comment: `1 + f()` means to execute `f()` and then add `1` to the value returned by `f()` once it has completed

Comment: I’m so sorry for my pea brain. Could you explain step by step how my program runs. Which part does the counter start adding up? Only in recursive function the number wont get add to the function or something? It starts adding up after reaching the deepest level or before that?

Comment: @AZINEZ Take a small number, for example `n=10`, and follow the code step by step into all recursive calls while writing down all return values. It should start making sense then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to simplify, I am going to introduce another function that counts how many times we have to divide by 2 to reach zero:

```
int f(int i)
{
  if (i == 0)
    return 0; 
  else
    return 1 + f(i/2);
}
```

Now, if we assume c does evaluation by expanding functions, we can see how `f(7)` gets evaluated. When we call `f`,  `i` will have the value `7` which is `!=0`, and we will have the following expansion:

```
f(7) -> 1 + f(7/2)
     -> 1 + f(3)
```

In the next call of `f`, `i` will have the value `3`, which is also `!=0`, and `f(3)` will expand to `1 + f(3/2)`:

```
f(7) -> 1 + f(7/2)
     -> 1 + f(3)
     -> 1 + (1 + f(3/2)) 
     -> 1 + (1 + f(1))
```

...and now with 'i=1':

```
f(7) -> 1 + f(7/2)
     -> 1 + f(3)
     -> 1 + (1 + f(3/2)) 
     -> 1 + (1 + f(1))
     -> 1 + (1 + (1 + f(1/2)))
     -> 1 + (1 + (1 + f(0)))
```

With `i=0`, `f(0)` expands to `0`, so we have:

```
f(7) -> 1 + f(7/2)
     -> 1 + f(3)
     -> 1 + (1 + f(3/2)) 
     -> 1 + (1 + f(1))
     -> 1 + (1 + (1 + f(1/2)))
     -> 1 + (1 + (1 + f(0)))
     -> 1 + (1 + (1 + 0))
     -> 3
```

I am sure if you manage to understand this example, you should also manage to adapt the explanation to your own `collatz` function.

Just remember that c does not actually work by expanding functions and expressions, but it is sometimes a good mental model.

To better understand what is actually going on, you should run your program, step by step, in a debugger, and watch your variables and the stack.

Comment: Thank you, this is much better! Thank you so much !